# Filter - Calculated fields relation in Tableau

Tags: count, tableau-api

I have 20 lists of servers. Suppose we have 50 servers and everyday (for 20 days) we get a list of active servers. 
Having this list, I want to calculate the number of times each server has appeared in the lists. Suppose that Server1 has appeared in 16 out of these 20 lists. Here's how I'm doing it:

1. new calculated field: `{FIXED [Server]:COUNT([Server])}`
2. move this calculated field to columns
3. calculate CNTD (count distinct) and put it in rows

here's the results:
[image]
Now here comes the question:
What if I want to draw the very same chart, but only according to the last 5 lists (lists we've got the last 5 days)? If I filter based on paths and take the last 5 lists, the numbers calculated in calculated fields won't update. they're gonna still be 6,8,...16 while there are only 5 lists (the maximum number of appearance should be 5). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the FIXED level-of-detail (LOD), use INCLUDE. The order of operations for LOD calculations will run FIXED calculations run before applying any filtering. INCLUDE/EXCLUDE are applied after filtering.

`{INCLUDE [Server]:COUNT([Server])}`

This image from the online help shows the order of operations for LOD calculations and filtering.

[image]

See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html for more details.

Comment: This is great! I knew there was a way! Thanks a lot.

Comment: so, why should we use fixed at all? like when we want a total count for percentage no matter what filter we are using?

Comment: @Mohsen, that is exactly the purpose of FIXED. Take the SuperStore dataset for example. You want to look at the details of one individual product. Yet you still want to know how that product performed compared to all products (% of total revenue) without having to display all the other products.